# jogo de damas em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz

eu tenho uma matriz de um estado de jogo de damas, como eu posso saber quais as peças ameaçadas no tabuleiro?

x5 é as peças pretas ameaçadas e x6 é as peças vermelhas ameaçadas, ou seja, quero saber como calcular o x5 e x6.

o código é o seguinte:

```
def estado_do_jogo_inicial():
    matriz= [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
             [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
             [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2],
             [2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0]]

    return matriz

def caracteristicas_do_estado_de_jogo(estado_do_jogo):
    x1=x2=x3=x4=x5=x6=0

    for i in range (len(estado_do_jogo)):
        for j in range(len(estado_do_jogo[i])):
            if estado_do_jogo[i][j] == 1:
                x1 += 1 
            elif estado_do_jogo[i][j] == 2:
                x2 += 1
            elif estado_do_jogo[i][j] == 11:
                x3 += 1
            elif estado_do_jogo[i][j] == 22:
                x4 += 1

    return x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6

    x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6 = caracteristicas_do_estado_de_jogo(e1)

    print(f'a quantidade de peças pretas no tabuleiro (x1) é igual à: ', x1)
    print(f'a quantidade de peças vermelhas no tabuleiro (x2) é igual à: ', x2)
    print(f'a quantidade de damas pretas no tabueleiro (x3) é igual à: ', x3)
    print(f'a quantidade de damas vermelhas no tabuleiro (x4) é igual à: ', x4)
```

Comment: O melhor será você percorrer o array e verificar se os vizinhos têm o campo vazio, ou se têm alguma peça sua ou do adversário. O que é que já tentou? Tem algum código das suas tentativas?

Comment: @leticia - como a minha resposta envolve funcionalidades mais avançadas da linguagem do que você estava usando, qualquer dúvida pode escrever. (outra pergunta, ou comentário aqui)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para saber sobre peças ameaçadas, tem que ser uma verificação que olhe, para cada peça, as diagonais todas em que ela está, e se tem alguma peça "atrás". Como você está levando em conta as damas, tem que olhar todas as casas para trás, na mesma diagonal - não basta colocar alguns "if" e olhar as casas adjacentes.

Então, a recomeendação aí é estruturar um pouco melhor a representação do tabuleiro, em vez de simplesmente "listas dentro de listas" - criar uma classe que permita você digitar pouco para saber o que há em cada casa - em Python, uma classe com o método `__getitem__`, por exemplo, permite o uso de coordenadas do tabuleiro direto nos colchetes. E aí você pode colocar vários métodos pequeninhos para verificar diagonais e posições, e compor o seu uso. Métodos para mover peças que verifiquem a legalidade de um movimento, e assim por diante.

Aproveitando o ensejo, também vale a pena criar uma classe simples para representar as peças de jogo, em vez de usar valores arbitrários como 1, 11, 2 e 22 - que podem permitir comparações "espertas" que só voltem "True", por exemplo, se a peça do outro lado for do oponente sem ter que duplicar toda a lógica das comparações.

Resumindo - não tem atalho - Quanto mais você conseguir fatorar o código em pequenas funções e abstrair coisas do tipo, usar posições relativas, mais legível fica o código final.

Criei uma classe tabuleiro aqui - para facilitar inclui uma função que pode popular o tabuleiro a partir da lista de listas como você criou - 
Eu uso coordenadas a partir do canto inferior esquerdo, de 0 até 7 e 0 até 7, ou a notação para coordenadas "A1, B1, até  H8", usada em tabuleiros de xadrez - então ao popular eu inverto a coordenada y.
(também é muito bom poder visualizar o que está no tabuleiro - então inclui uma representação para as peças e casas pretas usando caracteres unicode - eu pesquisei por "circle" aqui: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=circle&preview=entity ) )

Quanto ao algoritmo em si para localizar as peças ameaçadas, é como descreveriamos a tarefa em português:

- para cada posicao  do tabuleiro,:

  - se existir uma peça do time desejado na posição:
  - para cada direção diagonal:

    - se a casa oposta existe e está livre e\
    - se seguindo a diagonal há uma peça normal ou uma dama do oponente:

      - então adicionar 1 a contagem de ameaças

---

```
class PlayingPiece:
    def __init__(self, type, team):
        self.type = type
        self.team = team

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.team == other.team

    def __str__(self):
        # ◯ , ⏺, ②, ❷
        return (
            "\N{LARGE CIRCLE}" if self.type == "peça" and self.team == "vermelha" else
            "\N{BLACK CIRCLE FOR RECORD}" if self.type == "peça" and self.team == "preta" else
            "\N{CIRCLED DIGIT TWO}" if self.type == "dama" and self.team == "vermelha" else
            "\N{DINGBAT NEGATIVE CIRCLED DIGIT TWO}"
        )


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.type} {self.team}"

teams = ["preta", "vermelha"]
types_ = ["peça", "dama"]


class Board:
    def __init__(self, size=(8,8)):

        self.size = size
        self.data = [None,] * (size[0] * size[1])
        self.player = teams[0]

    def load_from_legacy_lists(self, lists):
        for y, row in enumerate(lists):
            y = self.size[0] - 1 - y
            for x, p in enumerate(row):
                piece = (None if p == 0 else
                    PlayingPiece("peça", "preta") if p == 1 else
                    PlayingPiece("peça", "vermelha") if p == 2 else
                    PlayingPiece("dama", "preta") if p == 11 else
                    PlayingPiece("dama", "vermelha")
                )
                if piece:
                    self[y, x] = piece


    def filter_pos(self, pos):
        if 0 <= pos[0] < self.size[0] and 0 <= pos[1] < self.size[1]:
            return True
        return False

    def black_pos(self, pos):
        return not (pos[0] + pos[1] % 2) % 2

    def _norm_pos(self, pos):
        if len(pos) != 2:
            raise ValueError()
        if isinstance(pos, str):
            pos = (ord(pos[0].lower()) - ord("a"), int(pos[1]) - 1)
        if not self.black_pos(pos):
            raise ValueError("Coordenada não está nas casas pretas")
        if not self.filter_pos(pos):
            raise ValueError("Coordenada inválida")
        return pos


    def __getitem__(self, pos):
        pos = self._norm_pos(pos)
        return self.data[self.size[0] * pos[0] + pos[1]]

    def __setitem__(self, pos, value):
        pos = self._norm_pos(pos)
        if value is not None and not isinstance(value, PlayingPiece):
            raise TypeError("Apenas peças de jogo ou None são aceitos")
        self.data[self.size[0] * pos[0] + pos[1]] = value

    def iter_directions(self):
        for y in -1, 1:
            for x in -1, 1:
                yield y, x

    def _check_menace(self, pos, direction):
        other_dir = -direction[0], -direction[1]
        oposite_square = pos[0] + other_dir[0], pos[1] + other_dir[1]
        if not self.filter_pos(oposite_square) or self[oposite_square]:
            # não há casa oposta, ou está ocupada
            return False
        for i in range(1, 1 + self.size[0]):
            square = pos[0] + i * direction[0], pos[1] + i * direction[1]
            if not self.filter_pos(square):
                # fora do tabuleiro
                return False
            item = self[square]
            if item and item.team != self.player and (
                i == 1 or item.type == "dama"
            ):
                return True

    def __iter__(self):
        """yield all valid board positions"""
        for y in range(self.size[0]):
            for x in range(self.size[1]):
                try:
                    self._norm_pos((x,y))
                except ValueError:
                    continue
                yield (y, x)

    def count_menace(self, pos):
        pos = self._norm_pos(pos)
        piece = self[pos]
        last_direction = None
        menace_count = sum(int(self._check_menace(pos, direction))  for direction in self.iter_directions())
        return menace_count


    def count_team_menace(self, team):
        self.team = team
        menaces = 0
        for pos in self:
            if self[pos] and self[pos].team == team:
                menaces += self.count_menace(pos)
        return menaces

    def __repr__(self):
        lines = []
        for y in range(self.size[0] - 1, -1, -1):
            line = ""
            for x in range(self.size[1]):
                if not self.black_pos((y, x)):
                    line += " "
                    continue
                item = self[y, x]
                line += ("\u2588" if not item else
                        str(item)
                    )
            lines.append(line)
        return "\n".join(lines)
```

Usando isso no modo interativo:

```
In [120]: aa = Board() 
     ...: aa[0,0] = PlayingPiece("peça", "vermelha") 
     ...: aa[1, 1] = PlayingPiece("peça", "preta") 
     ...:  
     ...:                                                                                                                         

In [121]: aa                                                                                                                      
Out[121]: 
 █ █ █ █
█ █ █ █ 
 █ █ █ █
█ █ █ █ 
 █ █ █ █
█ █ █ █ 
 ⏺ █ █ █
◯ █ █ █ 

In [122]: aa.count_team_menace("preta")                                                                                           
Out[122]: 1
```

Comment: "_Como você está levando em conta as damas, tem que olhar todas as casas para trás, na mesma diagonal_" No Brasil a gente realmente joga dessa forma, mas há muitos países em que a dama só pode andar 1 casa (a diferença entre a dama e a peça normal, neste caso, é que a dama pode andar pra trás também). Eu acredito que o OP está se baseando nas regras brasileiras, mas o ideal era o OP explicar esse detalhe, que é crucial pro algoritmo.

Comment: Eu realmetne olho as 4 direçoes - mas o "trás" nessa frase é em relação a distância - "atrás da peça que está sendo levada em consideração" - nessa frase, em qualquer das 4 direções.

O tabuleiro não implementa as regras completas do jogo - para fazer isso, como você diz, é necessário saber _quais_ regras,  e preferencialmente deixar configurável.